# Is it possible to include libraries in a node_modules folder in a visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

I am wanting to utilize ReactJS and JSForce along with the Kendo UI for React.

I found CDN links for React and JSForce, which allows me to add them as sources in a scrip tag. However, I cannot find CDN links for Kendo UI for React. All their seems to be is an npm download and I cannot find useful information on including these in a visualforce page, or if it is possible.

If it is possible, how do you include these npm libraries? If not, will I have to make a page outside of Salesforce and use JSForce and connect to my instance so I can query and manipulate org data/objects?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need to figure out how to link a script via `Static Resource`. Have a read of [Referencing a Static Resource in Visualforce Markup](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_resources_reference.htm):

> - The way you reference a static resource in Visualforce markup depends on whether you want to reference a stand-alone file, or whether you want to reference a file that is contained in an archive (such as a .zip or .jar file):
>
>   To reference a stand-alone file, use `$Resource.<resource_name>` as a merge field, where `<resource_name>` is the name you specified when you uploaded the resource. For example:
>
>   ```
>   <apex:image url="{!$Resource.TestImage}" width="50" height="50"/>
>   ```
>
>   or
>
>   ```
>   <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.MyJavascriptFile}"/>
>   ```
> - To reference a file in an archive, use the URLFOR function. Specify the static resource name that you provided when you uploaded the archive with the first parameter, and the path to the desired file within the archive with the second. For example:
>
>   ```
>   <apex:image url="{!URLFOR($Resource.TestZip,
>             'images/Bluehills.jpg')}" width="50" height="50"/>
>   ```
>
>   or
>
>   ```
>   <apex:includeScript value="{!URLFOR($Resource.LibraryJS, '/base/subdir/file.js')}"/>
>   ```

Comment: But, the kendo files for React I want to utilize are only available through npm install, and every example shows them being added by `import kendo from '@progress/kendo-ui';`. I don't know if these can just be taken from the node_modules folder and thrown in a static resource and work.

Comment: @TylerDahle The ZIP file Static Resources gives access to all of its files automatically. As long as you create the ZIP storing the paths (default behavior for most ZIP programs), your relative URLs should all work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

IMO, the best way to do this would be to use [webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) to bundle your javascript into 1 or more bundles and then include those via a static resource.  I have a working example of how this works in the [B.A.S.S. Starter](https://github.com/ChuckJonas/bad-ass-salesforce-stack/blob/master/config/webpack.config.js).  While the implementation in this example quite complex, using webpack to bundle your javascript resources is actually quite simple.